# Coverter the type in the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

how to convert to the form like me in the example below:
ex:

*[a, b, c,d ] >> [(a,b) (c,d)]*

```
[a,b,c,d] 
#wish to be like this
[(a,b) (c,d)]
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the generalization here? If you want `[(a,b) (c,d)]` then `wanted = [(a,b) (c,d)]` works fine. Please explain the logic of how you get from `[a, b, c, d ]` to `[(a,b) (c,d)]`. What should `[a, b, c, d, e]` be? Why? Are you just looking for [chunking to a size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
n = 2
lst = []
for i in range(0, len(l), n):
    lst.append(tuple(l[i:i + n]))
#Output
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: i found the fix it was to use dlib:
dlib.rectangle(a,b,c,d)